# Как сделать ассоциации laravel?

Tags: laravel

Как сделать чтобы при значении `{{$lot->fuel}} = 1` Отображалось "бензин";
`2` - "дизель" и так далее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@if($lot->fuel == 1) "бензин"
@elseif($lot->fuel == 2) "дизель"
@endif
```